# Retrieve a CActiveDataProvider with a criteria in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm starting with yii and I have some trouble when trying to filter an CActiveDataProvider with a criteria.

This is my database model:

```
Table            Columns
Project          [id, name, status]
userToProject    [user_id,project_id,role]
User             [id , ....]
```

And I'd like the **index** action to show all the projects with status=finished or where the user is currently assigned to that project.

So hard-coding the user id for testing purposes. This is my code:

```
$criteria=array(
            'order'=>'status desc',
            'with'=>array(
               'userToProject','userToProject.user'=>array('alias'=>'user')),
    );
$criteria['condition']='status=='.Project::STATUS_FINISHED;
$criteria['condition'].=' OR user.id = 6';
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
$this->render('index',array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

But it throws an Exception saying **Unknown column 'user.id**. What am I missing? Thanks

Edit: The error code is:

```
 Column not found: 1054
 Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: 
 SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`name` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`description` AS `t0_c2`, 
 `t`.`status` AS `t0_c3`, `t`.`creation_date` AS `t0_c4` FROM `pgp_project` `t` WHERE
  (status=4 OR users.user_id=6) ORDER BY status desc LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Provide the full error message, including the SQL query that triggers it.

Comment: yes the exact sql and error message would be needed

Comment: I have no triggers in the tables. I'm going to check the error again

Comment: there is no join happening, are your sure you have relations in place? and please make sure you have no typos in the question's code

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(                    
    'order'=>'status desc',
    'with'   => array('userToProject'=>array('alias'=>'user')),
    'condition'=>'status='.Project::STATUS_FINISHED.' OR user.id = 6',
));

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Project', array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));

$this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```